# Probability question concerning "or more" given number of trials and probability of failure

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need help on a question and i do not have any idea on how to solve it, the question is what is the probability of 10 or more crashes happening in 1000 trials if the probability of crashing is .005. The or more is really hanging me up, if you could please explain it that would be great. thank you.

Comment: This event is the complement of 0, 1, 2, ..., or 9 crashes happening.

Comment: You did not state independence assumptions (and so the problem cannot be solved). However, most likely there are independence assumptions and this is a central limit theorem question.  So let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{1000}$ be Bernoulli random variables, where $X_i$ describes whether or not a crash occured on trial $i$.  Can you write the event $\{\mbox{There are 10 or more crashes}\}$ in terms of the $X_i$ variables?